# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__type')

Tags: angular, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Angular, Outlook add-in, I'm facing "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__type')" issue on retrieving the content of cloud file attachment, in other attachments, it's working but not working in the cloud file attachment
see the below code:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLBon.png)

```
 if (attachments.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0 ; i < attachments.length ; i++) {
      var options = { asyncContext: { type: attachments.attachmentType } };
      item.getAttachmentContentAsync(attachments[i].id,options , this.handleAttachmentsCallback);
    }
}
```

Error:-

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__type')
at i (isAttachmentOfItemType.ts:15:21)
at getAttachmentContentAsyncApiMethod.ts:45:9
at ln (executeApiMethod.ts:109:9)
at EndpointRegistrator.ts:41:9
at Microsoft.Office.Common.Invoker.invoke (osfruntime.js:19:51976)
at O (osfruntime.js:19:39836)
at U (osfruntime.js:19:43619)
```

[Show attachment object and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLBon.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The error is telling you that you are trying to access the property `__type` of some object, while the object is undefined. However in the code you attached to the question, there is no property access to `__type`. Please add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: @Gaurav Can you please share some screenshot/video which shows how you are attaching a Cloud Attachment? That will help us understand the scenario. We understand and acknowledge that "id" which is being returned as URL seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
var options = { asyncContext: { type: attachment.attachmentType } };
item.getAttachmentContentAsync(attachment.id, options, function (result) 
{
    if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) 
    {
        //console.log("Call returned success!");
        var AttachmentContent = result.value; // Get the attachment content
        if (AttachmentContent.format == Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.Base64) 
        {
            // handle file attachment
            //console.log(attachment.name + " Base64 String: " + AttachmentContent.content);
            console.log("Downloaded " + attachment.name);
            fnCallback(AttachmentContent.content);
        }
        else if (result.format == Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.Eml) {
            // handle item attachment
        }
        else {
            // handle cloud attachment  
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        var err = result.error;
        console.log("Download failed: " + err.name + ": " + err.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but still getting the same error, I think it's coming from the outlook getAttachmentContentAsync function

Comment: Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: yes, an error comes from the outlook getAttachmentContentAsync function, Cloud file attachment id is containing file URL instead of location id that's why Outlook is unable to find out the document and it's generating an error in getAttachmentContentAsync function if you show attachment of this question might be you'll get better idea

Comment: On this outlook file line isAttachmentOfItemType.ts:15
export function isAttachmentOfItemType<T extends AttachmentType>(
    attachment: T
): attachment is T & ItemAttachment {
    return (
        (attachment.__type || (attachment as Schema.Attachment).OwsTypeName) ===
        ITEM_ATTACHMENT_TYPE
    );
}

Error is in this line
return (
        (attachment.__type || (attachment as Schema.Attachment).OwsTypeName) ===
        ITEM_ATTACHMENT_TYPE
    );
Error -> attachment.__type 
attachment is showing null

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following code snippet below? With Cloud attachment we are not getting any error with this.

```
// method to get the attachment content
function getContentById(id)
{
  if (id)
  {
    console.log("Getting content for attachment with id: " + id);
    Office.context.mailbox.item.getAttachmentContentAsync
    (
      id,
      function (asyncResult)
      {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(asyncResult));
      }
    );
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("item does not have attachment " + index);
  }
}

var index = 0; // 0 based index of the attachment you want to get content for.
if (Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments)
{
  var id;
  // read
  if (Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments.length > index)
  {
    id = Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments[index].id;
  }
  getContentById(id);
}
else
{
  // compose
  Office.context.mailbox.item.getAttachmentsAsync
  (
    function (asyncResult)
    {
      var id;
      if (asyncResult.status === "succeeded")
      {
        var attachments = asyncResult.value;
        if (attachments.length > index)
        {
          id = attachments[index].id;
        }
      }
      console.log("getAttachmentsAsync result: " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult));
      getContentById(id);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried the above code but still getting the same error:-

Getting content for attachment with id: https://<--domain-->/:w:/s//Ef-KwkwbbTFOrHfJesH4_GkBEN_-GcV7mtWOduLQz1vKrw

isAttachmentOfItemType.ts:15 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__type')

Comment: @Gaurav Can you please share some screenshot/video which shows how you are attaching a Cloud Attachment? That will help us understand the scenario. We understand that "id" which is being returned as URL seems wrong.